# Webtask.io backend cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless, webtask

I'm learning serverless backend and I'm trying webtask.io to deploy a simple backend to get the prices from cryptocurrency exchanges. My server is working fine when I deploy it locally, but when I try to deploy it in webtask.io I'm getting this error `Cannot find module './server/routes/api'`.

You can check the error here:

[WT error link](https://wt-2b048b219d93ba7322a7924ec0ac0ee3-0.run.webtask.io/wt-mern-api)

this is my code

index.js

```
var Express = require('express');
var Webtask = require('webtask-tools');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = Express();
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = Webtask.fromExpress(app);
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// declare axios for making http requests
const axios = require('axios');
const coinTicker = require('coin-ticker');

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('api works');
});

router.get('/clpbtc', function(req, res, next) {
  axios.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker')
  .then(response => {
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});

router.get('/ethbtc', function(req, res, next) {
  coinTicker('bittrex', 'ETH_BTC')
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.bid);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

router.get('/ltcbtc', function(req, res, next) {
  coinTicker('bittrex', 'LTC_BTC')
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.bid);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

router.get('/xrpbtc', function(req, res, next) {
  coinTicker('bittrex', 'XRP_BTC')
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.bid);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

router.get('/zecbtc', function(req, res, next) {
  coinTicker('bittrex', 'ZEC_BTC')
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.bid);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

router.get('/timer', function(req, res, next) {
  setInterval(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
}, 5000);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for your help as always!

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time to find out the solution for this issue because it is not so well documented in Webtask docs.

The key for to solve this issue is to use the `--bundle` flag in wt-cli

Example

**faucet.js** file

```
const bitgoHandler = require('./functions/bitgoHandler')
const to = require('await-to-js').default

module.exports = faucet

async function faucet ({body, data}, cb) {
  const [err, result] = await to(bitgoHandler.sendTransaction(body, data))
  if (err) return cb(err)
  cb(null, result)
}
```

**bitgoHandler.js** file

```
const BitGoJS = require('bitgo'); 
const to = require('await-to-js').default

module.exports = {   getWallet,   sendTransaction }

function getWallet (accessToken, faucetWalletId) {   
 const bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo({ env: 'test', accessToken });   
 const coin = bitgo.coin('tbtc');   
 return coin.wallets().get({id: faucetWalletId}) 
}

async function sendTransaction ({receiverAddress}, {ACCESS_TOKEN, FAUCET_WALLET_ID, WALLET_PASSPHRASE}) {   const [err, wallet] = await to(getWallet(ACCESS_TOKEN, FAUCET_WALLET_ID))   if (err) return Promise.reject(err)   
let params = {
    amount: 0.01 * 1e8,
    address: receiverAddress,
    walletPassphrase: WALLET_PASSPHRASE   
};   
return wallet.send(params) 
}
```

To deploy the whole application I've used the script below

`wt create -s ACCESS_TOKEN=<ACCESS_TOKEN> -s FAUCET_WALLET_ID=<FAUCET> -s WALLET_PASSPHRASE=<WALLET> --bundle faucet.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `--bundle` argument.

```
wt create --bundle index.js
```

Source: [webtask docs](https://webtask.io/docs/wt-cli)